# Pasting functions from subsets of a closure

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and $U \subseteq X$ (not necessarily open). Let $U_\alpha$ be a family of sets such that $U \subseteq U_\alpha \subseteq \text{cl}(U)$, and $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta = U$ for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then, given any family of continuous functions $f_\alpha : U_\alpha \to Y$ that agree on $U$, will their pasting $f : \bigcup U_\alpha \to Y$ necessarily be continuous?

It seems to me that it should be. If there were a case where it weren't, that would seem to mean that there would be subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\text{bd}(U)$ such that $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are "compatible" with $f|_U$ but not with each other, which would conflict with my intuition about boundaries.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: @hardmath That's $\bar U$ on the right, not $U$. Would it be clearer to use $\overline U$?

Comment: @hardmath I'll change it to $\text{cl}(U)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample with a non-Hausdorff (but otherwise quite nice) $Y$.

Let $Z$ be the [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins); I will denote the two origins by $0$ and $0'$. Let $X=\Bbb R^2$, and let $Y=Z\times\Bbb R$. Let

$$\begin{align*}
U&=\big(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\big)\times\Bbb R\;,\\
U_0&=U\cup\{\langle 0,y\rangle\in X:y<0\}\;,\text{ and}\\
U_1&=U\cup\{\langle 0,y\rangle\in X:y\ge 0\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Let

$$f_0:U_0\to Y:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$$

and

$$f_1:U_1\to Y:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle 0',y\rangle,&\text{if }x=0\\
\langle x,y\rangle,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $f_0$ and $f_1$ are continuous, and $f_0\upharpoonright U=f_1\upharpoonright U$, but $f_0\cup f_1:X\to Y$ is not continuous at the origin.